# How distribution key affects the distribution of data in netezza

Tags: netezza

If I specify the distribution key to be the primary key of a table, then is it fair to assume that the data will be distributed evenly across all nodes?

And if I specify the distribution key to be a column with only one value, then all the data will end up in the first node?

Answer (score 0):

> If I specify the distribution key to be the primary key of a table,
>   then is it fair to assume that the data will be distributed evenly
>   across all nodes?

Quibbling about the definition of a node aside, generally speaking choosing the primary key of a table to be the distribution method will distribute the data evenly across the data slices, but this may not hold for tables with a relatively small number of rows.

> And if I specify the distribution key to be a column with only one
>   value, then all the data will end up in the first node?

All of the data will be located on one data slice, but that may not be the "first one."